# C# database table name as variable return SQL syntax error

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this error when i start my winforms c# app:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near at line 1
```

I need to pass database table name as variable and that cause problem.
I have one form and when i pass to that form table name form show data for defined tabe in property.

Check my code what i do:
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private DataTable dt;
        private BindingSource bs;

```
    public string DatabaseTableName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bs = new BindingSource();

        this.PopulateDataGridView();
    }

private void PopulateDataGridView()
{

    string query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", DatabaseTableName);

    DataTable data = GetData(query); // ERROR is HERE

    bs.DataSource = data;

    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bs;
}



private DataTable GetData(string q)
{
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(Db.connStr))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(q, conn))
            {
                dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);

                return dt;
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

When i manualy enter `GetData("SELECT * FROM products")` all work good. But when i pass table name from variable or property i get error.

**UPDATE:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void listaKupacaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();

        form.DatabaseTableName = "products";

        form.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the content of `DatabaseTableName` here? What is the SQL query you are generating? Also, this is horribly open to SQL injection.

Comment: What is the value of `DatabaseTableName`?

Comment: Its database table name `form.DatabaseTableName = "products";`

Comment: And where is that being called? Are you sure it's being called?

Comment: I open this form in Parent form on button click event and show this form as dialog. I will update my question

Comment: Clearly `query` isn't what you assume it is.  So what is it?  Also, that error wouldn't be happening where you indicate it happens.  It would be happening *inside* that method being called.  It appears you need to debug this some more.

Comment: Check updated question

Comment: Your query runs in your constructor. After the constructor ran, you assign `DatabaseTableName`. That's too late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the order of events. You assume that your code is executing the `form.DatabaseTableName = "products";` line before the SQL is being run, but it's not. Your code is running in the form constructor, which means the `DatabaseTableName` variable has not been set.

A simple fix would be to pass in the value in the constructor, for example:

```
public Form1(string tableName)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    bs = new BindingSource();

    //Set it here
    this.DatabaseTableName = tableName;

    this.PopulateDataGridView();
}
```

And now when you create the form:

```
private void listaKupacaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form = new Form1("products");
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```